# Getting the state of a joystick button BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I've been trying to figure out a way to make a script that determines if a joystick button has been pressed, being held down or released. I managed to make it work with a keyboard button and then tried to convert my script to work with the joystick.

Here's the keyboard script (works by pressing H)

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

keyboardsens = cont.sensors["Keyboard"]

bStatus0 = keyboardsens.getKeyStatus(bge.events.HKEY)

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    print("just pressed")

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
    print("is pressed")

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_RELEASED:
    print("just released")
```

And here's the console output:

[image]

Here's the joystick script (works by pressing button 0, or in my case the B button):

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

joysticksens = cont.sensors["Joystick"]

bStatus0 = joysticksens.getButtonStatus(0)

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    print("just pressed")

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
    print("is pressed")

if bStatus0 == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_RELEASED:
    print("just released")
```

And here's this ones output:

[image]

See the problem I'm having here is that with the joystick, I don't get the initial "just pressed" or "just released" messages, just the in between "is pressed" message. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the button status, but the constants used are for sensor statuses. For those checkings, use `sensor.status` instead of `sensor.getButtonStatus`. Example:

```py
if joysticksens.status == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    print("just pressed")
```

Remember that `sensor.getButtonStatus` returns only `True` or `False`, and equals to the expression:

```py
BUTTON in bge.logic.joystics[0].activeButtons
```

Use the `sensor.getButtonStatus` along with `sensor.status` to check if a given button is pressed and which status of sensor at the same time.

Below, your file reworked using the method I mentioned, and few additions:

- Optimized by using Module mode instead of Script mode in controller
- Keyboard status checking without using the Keyboard sensor.

[image]